# Android method annotation for preventing call from being made on GUI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, annotations

In the project I'm currently working on there are plenty of caching which is done on the main thread which makes the app laggy. My plan is to make asynchronous variants of these, but still keeping the synchronous calls for easier chaining when combined in asyncTasks. The problem I have it that I want to prevent the usage of the caching functions in GUI thread in some intuitive way. Any ideas? Is it possible? Is it possible to mark a method with an annotation which prevents it from being called on the GUI thread?

Answer (score 4):

http://androidannotations.org/ provides a library that leverages the use of annotations to deal with this. They have annotations such as `@UiThread` and `@Background` that essentially replace the need to use `runOnUiThread()` and `AsyncTask` respectively.

If you're interested, here's a [paper](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~csgordon/papers/ecoop13.pdf) discussing a similar system for dealing with the blocking of UI thread operations from non-UI threads.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such possibility.

Maybe you can try with a "State machine' using Android.Handlers

**Checkout**

[Google Android Communication with UI Thread using Handlers](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

[**My favorite --->** Very clean and tidy article about Handlers!](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

It's worth googling out "state machine in android using handlers" too! This way I found a solution to my problem J.

I hope that you will find some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any annotations but it's a good idea to make it asynchronous. Personally I don't really care for AsyncTask as I think the code becomes quite messy, especially when you need to chain calls together etc, like you mentioned.

There are alternatives to AsyncTask that provides easier chaining, error handling etc. You could for example use promises. [JQ](https://github.com/code77se/jq%20JQ) is a promise library for Java7/Android that is basically a Java port of the JavaScript Promises/A+ spec. `Promise` is basically an extension of `Future` with chainable methods for observing completion using callbacks.

As an example (taken from the JQ docs), imagine the synchronous code with slow, blocking methods `foo`, `bar` and `baz`:

```
try {
  int x = foo();
  int y = bar(x);
  return baz(y);
} catch (Exception e) {
  return -1;
} finally {
  // Always called
}
```

could become

```
return foo().then(x -> {
  return bar(x);
}).then(y -> {
  return baz(y);
}).fail(e -> {
  return Value.wrap(-1);
}).fin({
  // Always called
});
```

(lambda shorthand used for reduced example verbosity, in reality you would write `then(new OnFulfilledCallback() {...})` etc, but Android Studio will make this quite simple and also auto-fold to some extent - or you could use [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) to get Java8-style lambda syntax with Java7.)

The implementation of methods `foo`, `bar` and `baz` would then return `Promise` and perform the actual work on a worker thread. You could facilitate this yourself, or use `JQ` provided tools for easy creation of promises with associated off-loading of work to a worker thread:

```
private Promise<Integer> foo() {
    return JQ.defer(() -> {
        int result = 42;

        // do some heavy processing...
        return result;
    });
}
```

Note that `JQ` also provides useful [utilities](https://code77se.github.io/jq/index.html?se/code77/jq/JQ.html) for synchronization of multiple parallel operations, adding timeouts to long-running operations, etc etc.

Disclaimer: Somewhat shameless promotion since I am the author of JQ. ;)